# FreeBSD on Home Routers?

Tags: networking, freebsd

Is it possible to install FreeBSD on a typical home router such as the NetGear DG834G?

Or is there an alternative that is suitable for a home setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FreeBSD only runs* on x86 and amd64 hardware. Since most home routers are using a different kind of cpu (like ARM) it will not work.

You can find a list of supported hardware over here: http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=44&Itemid=50

Personally I can recommend the Soekris hardware, but if you don't have the budget for that than ALIX is a reasonable alternative.

*as corrected by @wormsparty this is not 100% true, it is possible to *run* on other hardware but having a fully functioning router is a different question

Comment: Am I missing something? FreeBSD claims to support alpha, amd64, ARM, i386, ia64, MIPS, pc98, ppc, sparc64, sun4v, xbox.

Comment: @wormsparty: there's a difference between "runs on" and "fully functional". From my experience it can be quite the challenge to get a fully functional FreeBSD firewall on a MIPS system. I would be very interested in any articles claiming different because I have been looking for a way to replace my old router.

Comment: Upvoted unexplained downvote.

Comment: See [zrouter](http://zrouter.org/)